# Aplicar css a formulário apenas em um domínio

Tags: php, html, css

Bom dia.

Tenho um site que está disponível em br e em pt. Neste site tenho um formulário de contato:

```
<div class="form_cotation">
<header>
    <p><?php echo lang('request_cotation'); ?></p>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="toggle"><span class="icon_arrow_dw"></span></a>
</header>
<form name="cotation" class="form cotation" action="contact/send" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="form_input" value="FORM_COTACAO" />
    <div class="grid_1">
        <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="<?php echo lang('name') ;?>*" value="<?php echo lang('name') ;?>*" data-value="<?php echo lang('name') ;?>*" class="input watermark" />
    </div>
    <div class="grid_1">
        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="<?php echo lang('email') ;?>*" value="<?php echo lang('email') ;?>*" data-value="<?php echo lang('email') ;?>*" class="input watermark" />
    </div>
    <div class="grid_1">
        <div class="grid_1_1">
            <select id="country" name="country_code" data-size="10">
                <?php foreach($list_countries as $key => $value): ?>
                    <?php if($value->sPhoneCode != '0'): ?>
                        <option data-ddi="<?php echo $value->sPhoneCode; ?>" <?php echo lang('country_code') == $value->sISOCode ? 'selected="selected"' : ''; ?> data-iconurl="<?php echo base_url().'/upload/flags/'.$value->sISOCode; ?>.jpg" value="<?php echo $value->sISOCode; ?>"><?php echo $value->sName; ?> - <?php echo $value->sPhoneCode; ?></option>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="grid_1_2">
            <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="<?php echo lang('phone'); ?>" data-value="<?php echo lang('phone'); ?>" value="<?php echo lang('phone'); ?>" class="input watermark" />
        </div>
        <div class="grid_1_2" style="padding-top:10px;">
            <?php if(lang('abbr') == 'pt'): ?>
            <input type="text" name="locality" placeholder="Localidade*" data-value="locality" value="Localidade*" class="input watermark" style="width: 239px !important; " />
        <?php endif; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php if(lang('abbr') == 'pt'): ?>
        <input type="hidden" name="state" value="pt" />
        <input type="hidden" name="city" value="pt" />
    <?php else: ?>
        <div class="grid_1">
            <div class="grid_1_1">
                <select name="state" class="custom" data-width="76" data-value="UF*">
                    <option value="">UF*</option>
                    <option value="AC">AC</option>
                    <option value="AL">AL</option>
                    <option value="AP">AP</option>
                    <option value="AM">AM</option>
                    <option value="BA">BA</option>
                    <option value="CE">CE</option>
                    <option value="DF">DF</option>
                    <option value="ES">ES</option>
                    <option value="GO">GO</option>
                    <option value="MA">MA</option>
                    <option value="MT">MT</option>
                    <option value="MS">MS</option>
                    <option value="MG">MG</option>
                    <option value="PA">PA</option>
                    <option value="PB">PB</option>
                    <option value="PR">PR</option>
                    <option value="PE">PE</option>
                    <option value="PI">PI</option>
                    <option value="RJ">RJ</option>
                    <option value="RN">RN</option>
                    <option value="RS">RS</option>
                    <option value="RO">RO</option>
                    <option value="RR">RR</option>
                    <option value="SC">SC</option>
                    <option value="SP">SP</option>
                    <option value="SE">SE</option>
                    <option value="TO">TO</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="grid_1_2<?php echo lang('abbr') == 'pt' ? '_pt' : '' ?>">
                <input type="text" name="city" placeholder="<?php echo lang('city') ;?>*" value="<?php echo lang('city') ;?>*" data-value="<?php echo lang('city') ;?>*" class="input watermark" />
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <div class="grid_1">
        <div class="grid_1_<?php echo lang('abbr') == 'pt' ? '2_pt' : '3' ?>">
        <!--div class="grid_1_2"-->
            <input type="text" name="company" placeholder="<?php echo lang('company') ;?>*" value="<?php echo lang('company') ;?>*" data-value="<?php echo lang('company') ;?>*" class="input watermark" />
        </div>
        <?php
        if(lang('abbr') == 'pt'){
            ?>
            <input type="hidden" name="employers" value="" />
            <?php
        }else{
        ?>
        <div class="grid_1_4">
            <select id="employers" name="employers" class="custom" data-width="125" data-value="<?php echo lang('employers'); ?>*">
                <option value=""><?php echo lang('employers'); ?>*</option>
                <option value="0-10">0 - 10</option>
                <option value="11-25">11 - 25</option>
                <option value="26-80">26 - 80</option>
                <option value="81-150">81 - 150</option>
                <option value="150+">150+</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <?php 
        }
        ?>

    </div>

    <div class="grid_1">
        <textarea name="description" data-value="<?php echo lang('description'); ?>*" placeholder="<?php echo lang('description'); ?>*" class="watermark"><?php echo lang('description'); ?>*</textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="grid_1">
        <div class="right">*<?php echo lang('required_fields'); ?></div>
        <input type="submit" title="<?php echo lang('send');?>" class="btn" value="<?php echo lang('send');?>" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Como podem ver no código, de acordo com o domínio (pt ou br) o formulário recebe alguns campos diferentes. Porém, preciso fazer umas modificações de css em campos que aparecem em ambos, apenas no pt.

Como posso fazer isso para aplicar os estilos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Skyirn**, basta fazer da mesma maneira que estão hoje, usando `if` onde você desejar inserir o CSS:

```
<textarea (...) <?php if(lang('abbr') == 'pt'){ echo 'style="font-size: 10px;"'; } ?> >textarea</textarea>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Você pode escrever o seu `css` e verificar quando é pt, se for  você pode adicionar a class de `css` que você criou, exemplo:

```js
var isPt = true; 

if(isPt){ 
   $('#nome').addClass('nomePt');
}else{ 
   $('#nome').addClass('nomeBr');
}
```

```css
.nomePt{
    background:red;
}
.nomeBr{
    background:blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="nome" value="" id='nome'/>
```

você pode incluir o css direto do `js` exemplo:

```
$('#nome').css( 'background', 'black' );
```

ambos usando [jQuery](https://jquery.com/)

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, mas precisava de algo em php, como o @FelipeDouradinho me indicou!